# How come there is nothing in "Variables", "Watch" and "Call Stack" when I debug a file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Here is the image that shows the problem.

[image]

I am using Windows 11, python 3.10.

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you include more details in your question? Such as code (avoid using screen shots for this). This is so we can actually see where the break point is and what may be happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be **stopped** on a breakpoint in order for those panels to populate with data, otherwise, they will be empty. In your screenshot, you have a breakpoint, but you are not stopped on it. Additionally, watch won't contain anything unless you define some sort of expression.

See image below - I am stopped on a breakpoint, and the panel contains my locals.  I don't have any watches, so that's empty still.

[image: breakpoint]